# cannot spawn C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Git\cmd\: No such file or directory.

Tags: ssh, git-clone

I have a problem when I'm trying to clone with git on cygwin. My GIT_SSH is

```
 "C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Git\bin\".
```

When I try to clone, here is the result:

```
$ git clone ssh://*****/home/local/git/prestashop myDirectory
Cloning into 'myDirectory'...
error: cannot spawn C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Git\cmd\: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

I've seen many question related to that problem but I can't find answers to solve this problem. All ideas welcome ! Thanks !

Comment: Why using cygwin though? git for Windows works just fine too, and includes an openssh.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Following [Git with SSH on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8713121/6309), you see that GIT_SSH should reference the ssh executable, not just its path:

```
(old msysgit)
set GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\ssh.exe

(new 2015 git for Windows)
set GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe
```

Comment: Based on my Git for Windows install (2.5.0.windows.1), I didn't have ssh.exe at that path. I found mine at `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe`.

Comment: @IshmaelSmyrnow Good point. i have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, since I was using **Git Extension**s (3.3.1), I had adjust my **SSH Client** path.

Todo so, I went to Menu **Tools** > **Settings** > **Git Extensions** (category on left side) > **SSH** and adjusted my **SSH Client path** to **C:\Program Files\git\usr\bin\SSH.EXE**

### Update 1

Facing this issue once again, after switching to **Putty**, because **Pageant** allows me to set my private once a day without exposing outside, where I've forgot set **Putty** as my ssh client, by going to **Tools** > **Settings** > **Git Extensions** (category on left side) > **SSH** > And setting **Putty** as my ssh client