# Config git server: "fatal: '/C/Users/khanh/test.git' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, ssh, server, private

I have configured a private git server, i am using ssh protocol to clone the git repo, when i run git clone , below error appears:

[image]

Is there any way to solve it? Thanks

Comment: You may try the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499331/git-with-ssh-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the repo exists,you need to check on the server and also the url is correct.
To check you have correct access rights,you could just login with clone any repo.

```
ssh *user*@*server*
```

while user should be khanh and server is Win2k8 blabla。
After you found something wrong here,you should go back on git server configuration.