# git cant find correct ssh

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

When I try to connect using git, then I see this error

```
$ git clone git@github.com:MyCompany/eagle.git --verbose                                         
Cloning into 'eagle'...                                                                        
FATAL ERROR: Couldn't agree a key exchange algorithm (available: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sh
a2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521)                                                   
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                                        

Please make sure you have the correct access rights                                                  
and the repository exists.
```

I setuped all keys, etc and connection works fine, because when I do
`ssh -v git@github.com` connection is successful.

What could I do to understand what went wrong and what should be corrected ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `ssh -T git@github.com` gives you the:

```
Hi <name>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub
does not provide shell access.
```

message, that means your ssh setup is working.  If you get a:

```
FATAL ERROR: Couldn't agree a key exchange algorithm ...
```

that means your ssh setup *isn't* working.  Clearly there's a contradiction here, and the most likely culprit is that you have two different `ssh` commands installed: one that you are using, which works, and another that Git is using, which doesn't.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8713121/1256452) to [Git with SSH on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2499331/1256452) has a lot of upvotes.  I avoid Windows, so I have no idea whether this will help.  (I don't even know if you're on Windows since you have not mentioned it.)

Note that [Git version 2.3.0 added `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e3a80781f5932f5fea12a49eb06f3ade4ed8945c/Documentation/RelNotes/2.3.0.txt#L25-L27), and [Git version 2.10.0 added `core.sshCommand` to set a value for `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e3a80781f5932f5fea12a49eb06f3ade4ed8945c/Documentation/RelNotes/2.10.0.txt#L83-L84).  Since then, [Git version 2.13.0 learned some new tricks for dealing with issues tied to variations of ssh that demand different option letters.](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e3a80781f5932f5fea12a49eb06f3ade4ed8945c/Documentation/RelNotes/2.13.0.txt#L62-L69)  In all cases it's important to figure out which ssh Git is running, and make sure it runs one that actually works.  See [the top level Git documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html) for a description of all the option variables and what they do.  The link here goes to a web page that may not match your own Git version, so consider running `git --help git` to read that version, if your Git is very old.

Answer (score 14):

For me, this was happening because:

1. I had Git configured to use PuTTY (i.e. `GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe`)
2. I was running an old version of PuTTY (e.g. 0.63)
3. GitHub has recently [removed weak cryptography standards](https://blog.github.com/2018-02-23-weak-cryptographic-standards-removed/).

I uninstalled PuTTY 0.63 and [downloaded](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) and installed the latest version of PuTTY (at this time, 0.70), and that solved the problem for me.

Comment: I upgraded my PuTTY as well but after switching over to a different key type (trying to figure out one that sort of matched one in the list I was getting in the error). I ended up upgrading PuTTY only because Pagaent couldn't load the keys I had just created!

Answer (score 4):

the problem was in GIT_SSH. this variable has been set by putty before.
I deleted this env variable and problem has been solved

Answer (score 1):

This may have to do with GitHub [removing weak crypto](https://blog.github.com/2018-02-23-weak-cryptographic-standards-removed/). This happend about Feb 22, 2018.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using SourceTree, then putty, then open-ssh. Actually did a mess and was using the putty installed with SourceTree when checking `GIT_SSH` env variable value. Deleting this env variable was needed to use open-ssh. (not using putty so)

For neophyte I am using this snippet to "login" to github with open-ssh:
`eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add ~/.ssh/mySHHKey`

EDIT: nevermind I successfully connected yesterday but now it stopped working... Using pageant with putty in meantime.