# Why git fetch is not using the same keys as ssh -T?

Tags: git, ssh

I am working on windows 10 and I am trying to connect git via ssh with selfhosted(corporate) instance of gitlab.
I try to follow guide here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/. I am at the stage that `ssh -Tv git@corpo.gitlab` correctly logs me into the instance, however when I try to do `git fetch gitlab` ssh connection fails.

I have tried to compare debug output of standalone `ssh` invocation and `git` invoked ssh, and I have found out that in "git" variant, my private key is not even tried to be used. Logs says it looks in the correct user directory (so it is not an 'user scope' isse).

Why this can happen? I have added remote to the git repository via `git remote gitlab git@corp.gitlab`.

setting proper ssh `config` file with

```
 Host ssh.corpo.gitlab
     HostName ssh.corpo.gitlab
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_corpo_key
```

fixes the issue, but I think it should work without those additional settings. What could make the difference ?

Comment: Windows comes with its own `ssh`, and Git-for-Windows comes with *its* own `ssh`. The two implementations may not talk to each other properly. You can get Git to use the Windows ssh, although I don't know offhand what the right way to do that is.

Comment: You are very correct, I just checked that windows uses OpenSSH_for_Windows8 + LibreSSL while git invoked OpenSSH8 + Openssl. Different binaries are beeing used,therfore I have added "default" key only to the "windows" instance. This explains (answers) my question actualy.

Comment: @torek [`set GIT_SSH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8713121/7976758), e.g.

Comment: @phd How does that compare to setting `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` or `core.sshCommand`? (In particular, do Windows users and/or ecosystems have their own environment variable overrides they use for special purposes?)

Comment: @torek [`GIT_SSH`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITSSHcode) must point to a binary (or a script) and doesn't accept parameters. `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` allows complex command line. I don't think Git-for-Windows has its own environment variables.

Comment: I did not mean to ask if Git-for-Windows added even more environment variables to this list (although that's a fine question too :-) ), but rather things like: do 47 Windows IDEs export their own `GIT_SSH` and it's important for them to override this, which is why we recommend exporting `GIT_SSH` here? Or, do 12 IDEs export `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`, which overrides `GIT_SSH`, and the remaining 35 export nothing but should use your setting, in which case either one should be allowed, etc. That's the kind of ecosystem knowledge that determines which of all the various options is the "right" one.

Answer (score 0):

> I have added remote to the git repository via git remote gitlab git@corp.gitlab.

If you want to use your key, you would need a `~/.ssh/config` with:

```
Host corpo.gitlab
  Hostname ssh.corpo.gitlab
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_corpo_key
  User git
```

And the URL would become:

```
git remote set-url gitlab corpo.gitlab:<me>/<myrepo>
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                   (need to match the Host entry)
```